# How to disable autoplay of the movie in XHTML transitional

Tags: html, xhtml, xhtml-transitional

Here's my code

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" style="width:425px; height:349px;" data="multimedia/1.mp4">
<param name="movie" value="multimedia/1.mp4" />
<param name="autoplay" value="false" />
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
</object>
```

When i open my website, the movies are automatically playing.

What is the solution so i can disable the autoplay of my movies in my website that use XHTML transitional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd remove the autoplay attribute, since if the browser finds the autoplay string, it autoplays!

The autoplay is not a boolean type.

Also, the type goes inside the source, like this:

```
<video width="640" height="480" controls preload="none">
   <source src="http://example.com/mytestfile.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

**or**

Try adding autostart="false" to your source tag.

```
<video width="640" height="480" controls="controls" type="video/mp4" preload="none">
<source src="http://example.com/mytestfile.mp4" autostart="false">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ymV8J/144/)